# How to refresh and close parent window from simplemodal (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am using a simplemodal to open up another page through iframe. How could I close the modal window and refresh parent page after the page has successfully submitted? I don't want to close it if backend validation didn't pass.

- I submit modal window
- verify if backend validation succeded or not
- if yes, close the modal window and reload parent page
- if Not, show validation messages

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like the [Contact Form demo](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/#contact-form) would give you enough information on how to do that, unless that's not the right SimpleModal.